# How can I get eave rafters cut flush?

Tags: woodworking, exterior, carpentry

This may seem like a silly question, but I removed two old facia boards.  The beams butted against them are all uneven.  I've tried an orbital sander but can't seem to get it to sand evenly to flush.  The one in the photo I had to cut because of rot.  It's particularly bad as I had to cut it with a sawsall.

Any advice or suggestions would be awesome!  I'm new to working with wood.

[image]

Comment: An oscillating tool such as https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-4-Amp-Corded-JobMax-Multi-Tool-with-Tool-Free-Head-R28602/206824272 would probably work best. You can also just take your time with a hand saw; draw your cut line and go.

Comment: How are you using the word "flush" here? I'm not sure what the intended outcome is. I assume that you're scabbing in a new board to extend the rafter tail and need a square cut, but....

Comment: Good point. Since he's new to working with wood, I'm thinking that he might be new to the terminologically as well. I'm guessing that he means 'straight' (as in a straight cut). He probably also wants it plumb as well and doesn't realize that these mean two distinctly different things. Same for straight and square, similar but different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this and which of them to choose depends on many things including what tools are available and the skill of the person using the tools.

Back when I was a carpenter I would choose to use a reciprocating saw but this takes a decent level of skill to use to both get a good cut and also not hurt yourself. Upside, will cut through nails.
[image: Reciprocating saw]

Alternately, you could use a good pull saw and do it by hand. This is more effort and slower, but the slowness will work in your favor because it will allow you to focus more on the cut than the tool. Downside, any nails will ruin the saw.

[image: pull saw]

Comment: Thanks for the advice! ended up using a sawzall, drawing a line on both sides and cutting slowly, then I sanded down any rough spots.  Worked just fine